# FFMPEG killed - not much information for troubleshooting

Tags: ffmpeg

can't find out what might be causing this killed. Any tips? or what kind of logs might help to troubleshoot? It just says 'KILLED'.

This FFMPEG is installed in my AWS Linux (centos rhel fedora)
I am quite confident the file is OK as the ffmpeg runs ok on my local macos (but different ffmpeg installation from brew).

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x927f20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x927f20] profile High, level 5.1
[libx264 @ 0x927f20] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'fail.mp4':=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 3840x2160, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-27T17:14:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-27T17:14:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
Killed   37 fps= 18 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.484x
```

Here is my FFMPEG

```
ffmpeg version N-60236-gffb000fff8-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      57. 18.100 / 57. 18.100
  libavcodec     59. 20.100 / 59. 20.100
  libavformat    59. 17.100 / 59. 17.100
  libavdevice    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavfilter     8. 25.100 /  8. 25.100
  libswscale      6.  5.100 /  6.  5.100
  libswresample   4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libpostproc    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

I just got a debug log

```
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url failed.mp4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: failed.mp4.
[file @ 0x6c3d340] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 2 logical cores
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] Reinit context to 3840x2160, pix_fmt: yuv420p
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] no picture 
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6fe9780] Setting 'video_size' to value '3840x2160'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6fe9780] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6fe9780] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/30000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6fe9780] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6fe9780] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6fe9780] w:3840 h:2160 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/30000 fr:30/1 sar:0/1
[format @ 0x77af200] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21|yuv420p10le|yuv422p10le|yuv444p10le|nv20le|gray|gray10le'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x6fe8a00] query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[libx264 @ 0x70e7800] using mv_range_thread = 360
[libx264 @ 0x70e7800] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0x70e7800] profile High, level 5.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x70e7800] 264 - core 164 r3081 19856cc - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x6fc91c0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x6fc91c0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x6fc91c0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x6fc91c0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x6fc91c0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x70e6a80] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'fltp'
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x70e6a80] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '96000|88200|64000|48000|44100|32000|24000|22050|16000|12000|11025|8000|7350'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x70f2400] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
Output #0, mp4, to 'failed.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.17.100
  Stream #0:0(eng), 0, 1/15360: Video: h264, 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive, left), 3840x2160 (0x0), 0/1, q=2-31, 30 fps, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-27T17:14:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.20.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng), 0, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-27T17:14:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.20.100 aac
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 14 times
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 16 times
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 15 times
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 16 times
[h264 @ 0x6c44900] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x70354c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x6c407c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
Killed
```

Comment: Your command must have been killed by an external signal of some sort. The word `Killed` does not appear anywhere in its code base. The ffmpeg only prints a carriage return (`\r`) at the end of its progress log line (instead of `\n`), so it just appears as if ffmpeg printed the `Killed` log.

Comment: Thanks man. I tried to explore this a bit more and found out it was only not killed when I added a size. very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it only happens with width / size that are quite large (eg. > 3000).

When I added to scale to smaller size it worked. (And also have to not hit the divisible by 2 error)

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to chime in on this since it appears to be one of the questions appearing pretty high on Google when searching for this issue.

For me the problem, rather unexpected, was that I only gave the container running ffmpeg a total of 4 GiB of RAM. For some reason, even processing only a single frame was maxing out the RAM usage at 4,11 GiB (after increasing it). The "Killed" probably came from the Linux OOM Killer. Increasing it to 8 GiB made it run through successfully.